# Decoding JSON in PHP if it's not always in the same order

Tags: php, json

I've been stuck with a problem with JSON and PHP for a while now. I have a JSON object like:

```
{"statistics":[{"name":"someName"},{"name":"someName2"}]}
```

The problem is that `someName` sometimes takes `someNames2`'s playce and reverse, but I only want to show `someName2`. How do I do that? =(

Comment: json_decode()???
what have you tried?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Which data are you looking for?  How are you getting it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` to filter the `json` array where `name = someName2` .. this way `someName2` position would not matter ...

```
$json = '{"statistics":[{"name":"someName"},{"name":"someName2"}]}' ;
$array = json_decode($json,true);

$f = "someName2"; // What to find
$k = "name" ;  // Filed Name

$array = array_filter($array['statistics'],function($v)use($f,$k){ var_dump($v);return $v[$k] == $f;});
var_dump($array);
```